# why does `heroku run` hang when used in process substitution?

Tags: bash, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

This command seems to hang indefinitely:

`cat <( heroku run -a my-app echo hello )`

Why does that hang?

This works: `cat <( echo hello )`

as does this: `heroku run -a my-app echo hello | cat`

Adding the `--no-tty` option to `heroku run` doesn't help.

bash version 4.4.19 (installed on OS X via brew)

Comment: (I'm the lead engineer of the Heroku CLI) This is a very good question. Nobody has pointed this out yet. I've traced the issue down to this code block: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-run/blob/master/lib/dyno.js#L289-L314

If I comment it out, it behaves fine. This block is what enables stdin to read. I'm trying to figure out what it is in here that is causing the block.

Comment: Update: it's the `process.stdin.setRawMode(true)`. Now looking into why...

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss for a real fix, but [this patch](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-run/commit/1e5a492f5ad84f5df3ab5ea26216bf277bd96dcc) should make it work when using `--no-tty` at least.